# EF6 appends a '1' to the end of my table name, which doesn't exist and is not referenced in code. Is there a reason for this, and how is it fixed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My code is breaking on `db.SaveChanges()`, with the error being

> : 'An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.'

and an Inner Exception of:

> : 'Invalid object name 'dbo.Author_Books1'

The problem is, the `Author_Books1` table isn't referenced anywhere in my code.  It should be `Author_Books`, a link list for one-to-many relationships between an Author and the Books written by them.

My Author entity looks like:

```
[Table("Authors")]
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid AuthorId{ get; set; }
    public string AuthorName{ get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

My Books entity looks like:

```
[Table("Books")]
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid BookId{ get; set; }
    public Guid Bookname{ get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

My AuthorBook Entity looks like this:

```
[Table("Author_Books")]
public class AuthorBook
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid AuthorBookId{ get; set; }
    public Guid Author_AuthorId{ get; set; }
    public Guid Book_BookId{ get; set; }
}
```

AppDBContext is

```
public DbSet<AuthorBook> AuthorBooks{ get; set; }
```

And OnModelCreating() looks like:

```
// Author-Books
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>().Property(p => p.AuthorBookId).HasColumnType("UniqueIdentifier").IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>().Property(p => p.Author_AuthorId).HasColumnType("UniqueIdentifier").IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>().Property(p => p.Book_BookId).HasColumnType("UniqueIdentifier").IsRequired();
// Added to specifically state which db table to use...
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>().ToTable("Author_Books");
```

I'm reading the list of authors and the books they've written from an Excel sheet, parsing through the list of books (they're comma delimited), and then adding a new db.Entry for them.

```
// Parse column for multiple possible books
if (worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value != null)
{
    string[] possibleBooks = Regex.Split(worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString(), ", ");

    foreach (string book in possibleBooks)
    {
         Book newbook  = db.Books.Where(c => c.BookName == book).FirstOrDefault();
         Author.Books.Add(newbook);
         db.Entry(newbook).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
 }
```

And in my database object I've got:

```
public static ResponseMessage SaveAuthorsAndBook(AppDBContext db, List<Author> Authors)
{
    ResponseMessage ResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage();

    foreach (Author author in Authors)
    {
         db.Entry(author).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
    }
            
     db.SaveChanges();

     return ResponseMessage;
 }
```

I don't understand why it's looking for dbo.Author_Books1 when that's not being referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

EF core uses some conventions and try to decode the relations between tables.

I assume that the tables have Foreign keys in the database. If so, try explicitly mentioning the keys and mapping using annotations(on entity) or fluent mapping (in onModelCreating method)

Do you have AuthorBook entity being referenced in another entity. This might also cause an issue with ef deducing the wrong table.